# How works @Transactional timeout attribute with different propagations

Tags: spring, transactions, spring-3

I am confused with the behaviour of the @Transactional **timeout** attribute

I have the following sequence

```
Main -> 
UserExecutionServiceImpl.executeRecordInvoice ->
ProcessInvoiceServiceImpl.recordInvoice ->
WarehouseServiceImpl.checkStockAvailability
```

To force the rollback exception **timeout** is set to 0.

If **executeRecordInvoice** has `@Transactional(timeout=0)` the exception is thrown and there stop all. It has sense

If **executeRecordInvoice** has `@Transactional` and **recordInvoice** has `@Transactional(timeout=0)` the exception is not thrown. Practically the timeout value has been ignored.

I could assume because the transaction really begins with **executeRecordInvoice** and furthermore because both methods have by default `Propagation.Required`, it means, the second (**recordInvoice**) is considered within the first (**executeRecordInvoice**), the already existing transaction, which is running

Even more, I did two simple experiments:

1. If **executeRecordInvoice** has `@Transactional` and **recordInvoice** has `@Transactional(propagation.Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, timeout=0)` the exception is  thrown. Now works because a **new** Transaction begins in **recordInvoice** and therefore **timeout** is considered.
2. Call from the Main class directly the `ProcessInvoiceServiceImpl.recordInvoice`, it with `@Transactional(propagation.Propagation.REQUIRED, timeout=0)` or with `@Transactional(propagation.Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, timeout=0)`, again **timeout** is considered.

Until here, I am fine, and all has sense. But applying 1 and 2 for **WarehouseServiceImpl.checkStockAvailability**, it does not work:

1. If **executeRecordInvoice** and **recordInvoice** have `@Transactional` (therefore both Propagation.REQUIRED by default) and **checkStockAvailability** has `@Transactional(propagation.Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, timeout=0)`. The exception is **not** thrown!.
2. Call from the Main class directly the `WarehouseServiceImpl.checkStockAvailability`, it with `@Transactional(propagation.Propagation.REQUIRED, timeout=0)` or with `@Transactional(propagation.Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, timeout=0)`, again **timeout** is **not** considered.

Class declaration

```
@Service
@Transactional
@Scope("prototype")
public class WarehouseServiceImpl implements WarehouseService {

    // Unique method implementation
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, timeout=0)
    public boolean checkStockAvailability(Product product, BigDecimal quantity) {

        ...

    return true;

    }
}
```

Any idea or suggestion is welcome.

Spring Framework 4.0.5

Thank you.

After to do the suggestion of Andrei, I have the following:

```
@Transactional
@Scope("prototype")
@Service("processInvoiceService")
public class ProcessInvoiceServiceImpl implements ProcessInvoiceService {

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, timeout=0)
    public void recordInvoice(InvoiceHeader invoiceHeader) {
```

And in the MainTest class

```
ProcessInvoiceService processInvoiceService = context.getBean(ProcessInvoiceService.class);

        try{
            processInvoiceService.recordInvoice(invoiceHeader03);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            logger.error("ERROR ALFA: {}", e.getMessage());
        }
```

With shows the Console, part in the result output

```
Creating instance of bean 'processInvoiceService'
20:16:57,320 DEBUG ctory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: 249 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'productService'
20:16:57,320 DEBUG ctory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: 249 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'invoiceHeaderService'
20:16:57,320 DEBUG ctory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: 249 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'invoiceDetailService'
20:16:57,321 DEBUG ctory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: 449 - Creating instance of bean 'warehouseServiceImpl'
20:16:57,321 DEBUG ctory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: 249 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
20:16:57,321 DEBUG xy.InfrastructureAdvisorAutoProxyCreator: 593 - Creating implicit proxy for bean 'warehouseServiceImpl' with 0 common interceptors and 1 specific interceptors
20:16:57,321 DEBUG amework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy: 117 - Creating JDK dynamic proxy: target source is SingletonTargetSource for target object [com.manuel.jordan.model.service.support.impl.WarehouseServiceImpl@7b4c50bc]
20:16:57,321 DEBUG ctory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: 477 - Finished creating instance of bean 'warehouseServiceImpl'
20:16:57,322  INFO e.process.impl.ProcessInvoiceServiceImpl:  46 - ProcessInvoiceServiceImpl arg constructor
20:16:57,322 DEBUG ctory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: 249 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
20:16:57,322 DEBUG xy.InfrastructureAdvisorAutoProxyCreator: 593 - Creating implicit proxy for bean 'processInvoiceService' with 0 common interceptors and 1 specific interceptors
20:16:57,322 DEBUG amework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy: 117 - Creating JDK dynamic proxy: target source is SingletonTargetSource for target object [com.manuel.jordan.model.service.process.impl.ProcessInvoiceServiceImpl@5884a914]
20:16:57,322 DEBUG ctory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: 477 - Finished creating instance of bean 'processInvoiceService'
20:16:57,322 DEBUG ctory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: 249 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
20:16:57,322 DEBUG .datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager: 367 - Creating new transaction with name [com.manuel.jordan.model.service.process.impl.ProcessInvoiceServiceImpl.recordInvoice]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,timeout_0; ''
20:16:57,322 DEBUG k.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource: 138 - Creating new JDBC Driver Connection to [jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb]
20:16:57,323 DEBUG .datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager: 206 - Acquired Connection [org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection@50378a4] for JDBC transaction
20:16:57,323 DEBUG .datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager: 223 - Switching JDBC Connection [org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection@50378a4] to manual commit
20:16:57,323  INFO e.process.impl.ProcessInvoiceServiceImpl:  59 - ProcessInvoiceServiceImpl recordInvoice - start
20:16:57,323 DEBUG ctory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: 249 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
20:16:57,323 DEBUG .datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager: 472 - Participating in existing transaction
20:16:57,323 DEBUG ctory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: 249 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
20:16:57,323 DEBUG .datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager: 472 - Participating in existing transaction
20:16:57,324 DEBUG g.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate: 908 - Executing prepared SQL update
20:16:57,324 DEBUG g.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate: 627 - Executing prepared SQL statement [INSERT INTO invoiceheader(id, number, date, total) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)]
20:16:57,324 DEBUG .datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager: 854 - Participating transaction failed - marking existing transaction as rollback-only
20:16:57,324 DEBUG .datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager: 295 - Setting JDBC transaction [org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection@50378a4] rollback-only
20:16:57,324 DEBUG .datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager: 854 - Participating transaction failed - marking existing transaction as rollback-only
20:16:57,325 DEBUG .datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager: 295 - Setting JDBC transaction [org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection@50378a4] rollback-only
20:16:57,325 DEBUG .datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager: 847 - Initiating transaction rollback
20:16:57,325 DEBUG .datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager: 281 - Rolling back JDBC transaction on Connection [org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection@50378a4]
20:16:57,325 DEBUG .datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager: 324 - Releasing JDBC Connection [org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection@50378a4] after transaction
20:16:57,325 DEBUG ramework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils: 327 - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
20:16:57,325 ERROR          com.manuel.jordan.main.MainTest:  93 - ERROR ALFA: Transaction timed out: deadline was Mon Jun 30 20:16:57 PET 2014
20:16:57,325 DEBUG ctory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: 249 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
```

the error message appears how is expected..

Now for the other class

```
@Service
@Transactional
@Scope("prototype")
public class WarehouseServiceImpl implements WarehouseService {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WarehouseServiceImpl.class);

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, timeout=0)
    public boolean checkStockAvailability(Product product, BigDecimal quantity) {
```

And in the MainTest class

```
WarehouseService warehouseService = context.getBean(WarehouseService.class);

        try{
            logger.info("Pre");
            boolean result = warehouseService.checkStockAvailability(product01, BigDecimal.ZERO);
            logger.info("result: {}", result);
            logger.info("Post");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            logger.error("ERROR BETA: {}", e.getMessage());
        }
```

With shows the Console, part in the result output

```
20:16:57,337 DEBUG ctory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: 449 - Creating instance of bean 'warehouseServiceImpl'
20:16:57,337 DEBUG ctory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: 249 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
20:16:57,338 DEBUG xy.InfrastructureAdvisorAutoProxyCreator: 593 - Creating implicit proxy for bean 'warehouseServiceImpl' with 0 common interceptors and 1 specific interceptors
20:16:57,338 DEBUG amework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy: 117 - Creating JDK dynamic proxy: target source is SingletonTargetSource for target object [com.manuel.jordan.model.service.support.impl.WarehouseServiceImpl@23f5b5dc]
20:16:57,338 DEBUG ctory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: 477 - Finished creating instance of bean 'warehouseServiceImpl'
20:16:57,338  INFO          com.manuel.jordan.main.MainTest: 102 - Pre
20:16:57,338 DEBUG ion.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource: 108 - Adding transactional method 'WarehouseServiceImpl.checkStockAvailability' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,timeout_0; ''
20:16:57,338 DEBUG ctory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: 249 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
20:16:57,339 DEBUG .datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager: 367 - Creating new transaction with name [com.manuel.jordan.model.service.support.impl.WarehouseServiceImpl.checkStockAvailability]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,timeout_0; ''
20:16:57,339 DEBUG k.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource: 138 - Creating new JDBC Driver Connection to [jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb]
20:16:57,339 DEBUG .datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager: 206 - Acquired Connection [org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection@34bde49d] for JDBC transaction
20:16:57,339 DEBUG .datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager: 223 - Switching JDBC Connection [org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection@34bde49d] to manual commit
20:16:57,339 DEBUG .datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager: 755 - Initiating transaction commit
20:16:57,339 DEBUG .datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager: 266 - Committing JDBC transaction on Connection [org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection@34bde49d]
20:16:57,339 DEBUG .datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager: 324 - Releasing JDBC Connection [org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection@34bde49d] after transaction
20:16:57,339 DEBUG ramework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils: 327 - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
20:16:57,339  INFO          com.manuel.jordan.main.MainTest: 104 - result: true
20:16:57,339  INFO          com.manuel.jordan.main.MainTest: 105 - Post
```

The error was not thrown how it was expected..

**Omicron**

New updated code:

```
@Service
@Transactional
@Scope("prototype")
public class WarehouseServiceImpl implements WarehouseService {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WarehouseServiceImpl.class);

    private ProductService productService;

    @Autowired
    public WarehouseServiceImpl(ProductService productService){
        this.productService = productService;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, timeout=0)
    public boolean checkStockAvailability(Product product, BigDecimal quantity) {

        logger.info("Amount: {}", this.productService.getAmountProducts());
        ...     
        return true;

    }

}
```

The code shown above is the same for the two projects, for one working with JdbcTemplate, all OK, the expected error is thrown, but the other project working with Hibernate doesn't throws the expected error. Below the result output.

```
08:27:06,782  INFO          com.manuel.jordan.main.MainTest: 102 - Pre
08:27:06,782 DEBUG ctory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: 249 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
08:27:06,782 DEBUG m.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager: 367 - Creating new transaction with name [com.manuel.jordan.model.service.support.impl.WarehouseServiceImpl.checkStockAvailability]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,timeout_0; ''
08:27:06,783 DEBUG m.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager: 417 - Opened new Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@57ce634f updates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@b8a7e43 deletions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@35835fa orphanRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@56f71edb collectionCreations=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@7207cb51 collectionRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@2a27cb34 collectionUpdates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@6892cc6f collectionQueuedOps=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@6fd1660 unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])] for Hibernate transaction
08:27:06,783 DEBUG m.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager: 427 - Preparing JDBC Connection of Hibernate Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@57ce634f updates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@b8a7e43 deletions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@35835fa orphanRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@56f71edb collectionCreations=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@7207cb51 collectionRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@2a27cb34 collectionUpdates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@6892cc6f collectionQueuedOps=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@6fd1660 unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])]
08:27:06,783 DEBUG gine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl: 226 - Obtaining JDBC connection
08:27:06,783 DEBUG k.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource: 138 - Creating new JDBC Driver Connection to [jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb]
08:27:06,783 DEBUG gine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl: 232 - Obtained JDBC connection
08:27:06,783 DEBUG .transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl: 160 - begin
08:27:06,783 DEBUG ransaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction:  69 - initial autocommit status: true
08:27:06,783 DEBUG ransaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction:  71 - disabling autocommit
08:27:06,784 DEBUG m.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager: 488 - Exposing Hibernate transaction as JDBC transaction [org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection@4a6c18ad]
08:27:06,784 DEBUG ctory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: 249 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
08:27:06,784 DEBUG m.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager: 362 - Found thread-bound Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@57ce634f updates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@b8a7e43 deletions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@35835fa orphanRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@56f71edb collectionCreations=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@7207cb51 collectionRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@2a27cb34 collectionUpdates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@6892cc6f collectionQueuedOps=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@6fd1660 unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])] for Hibernate transaction
08:27:06,784 DEBUG m.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager: 472 - Participating in existing transaction
08:27:06,784 DEBUG ctory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: 249 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
08:27:06,784 DEBUG m.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager: 362 - Found thread-bound Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@57ce634f updates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@b8a7e43 deletions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@35835fa orphanRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@56f71edb collectionCreations=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@7207cb51 collectionRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@2a27cb34 collectionUpdates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@6892cc6f collectionQueuedOps=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@6fd1660 unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])] for Hibernate transaction
08:27:06,784 DEBUG m.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager: 472 - Participating in existing transaction
08:27:06,785 DEBUG                        org.hibernate.SQL: 109 - select count(*) as col_0_0_ from product product0_
08:27:06,785 DEBUG              org.hibernate.loader.Loader: 951 - Result set row: 0
08:27:06,786 DEBUG              org.hibernate.loader.Loader:1485 - Result row: 
08:27:06,786  INFO ervice.support.impl.WarehouseServiceImpl:  45 - Amount: 6
08:27:06,786 DEBUG m.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager: 755 - Initiating transaction commit
08:27:06,786 DEBUG m.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager: 551 - Committing Hibernate transaction on Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@57ce634f updates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@b8a7e43 deletions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@35835fa orphanRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@56f71edb collectionCreations=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@7207cb51 collectionRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@2a27cb34 collectionUpdates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@6892cc6f collectionQueuedOps=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@6fd1660 unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])]
08:27:06,786 DEBUG .transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl: 175 - committing
08:27:06,786 DEBUG ransaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction: 113 - committed JDBC Connection
08:27:06,786 DEBUG ransaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction: 126 - re-enabling autocommit
08:27:06,787 DEBUG m.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager: 633 - Closing Hibernate Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@57ce634f updates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@b8a7e43 deletions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@35835fa orphanRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@56f71edb collectionCreations=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@7207cb51 collectionRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@2a27cb34 collectionUpdates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@6892cc6f collectionQueuedOps=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@6fd1660 unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])] after transaction
08:27:06,787 DEBUG gine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl: 246 - Releasing JDBC connection
08:27:06,787 DEBUG gine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl: 264 - Released JDBC connection
08:27:06,787  INFO          com.manuel.jordan.main.MainTest: 104 - result: true
08:27:06,787  INFO          com.manuel.jordan.main.MainTest: 105 - Post
```

Some clue? DataAccess exists of course...

Comment: Check  the logs. Do you see messages about transactions being created/committed? This should be a good indication if your methods are really transactional and, if so, what parameters are used. Enable DEBUG level logging and test your application. I can take a look at your log file if you could post it at [http://pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com).

Comment: Thanks Andrei, definitively something is weird here, I am going to do this check this weekend. Thank You

Comment: Andrei, done… thanks in advance..New content available starting from "After to do the suggestion of Andrei"

Comment: And what do you do in `checkStockAvailability`? I see no database queries as I see in `recordInvoice`: `Executing prepared SQL statement [INSERT INTO invoiceheader(id, number, date, total) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)]`. Otherwise, the logs are pretty clear that a transaction is started with the correct settings: requires_new, timeout 0 etc.

Comment: Yes, no interaction with the database, I thought it was not necessary. I thought @Transactional should be agnostic about what happen within the method. Interesting. I've edited the source code to include a simple call to the DB, now all works fine, the timeout attribute now works how is expected. Thank You.

Comment: Now I am wondered with the following situation: I've two projects with the same business logic (source code), but one project works with JdbcTemplate and the other works with Hibernate. Both have the "new" code that calls the Database, only the project with JdbcTemplate throws the exception, but Hibernate doesn't. Sharing above the new code and the result output for Hibernate project in Debug mode, check the term "Omicron". Let me know what is happening now..thanks in advance.

Comment: If there is no activity with the database, then there is no database level transaction :-). What you have in java code reflect at db level. If, for example, you open a MySQL console and insert something in a table. At the end you need to commit to see the results in DB ;-). That's the transaction.

Comment: I looked in the source code for the Hibernate transaction and it seems that only values strictly greater than 0 are considered. See [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.1.0.Final/org/hibernate/engine/transaction/internal/jdbc/JdbcTransaction.java#83). Try something: set the timeout for Hibernate to 1 (that is one second). And in your `checkStockAvailability` method do something like this: Thread.currentThread.sleep(1500); If this throws the expected error, then it means Hibernate doesn't consider 0 seconds timeout, only strictly positive values.

Comment: Thank You. All has sense now. Valuable your two latest comments. Now all is clear :-) Thank you!

Comment: :-) no problem. If you believe it's worth adding something like a summary of what has been discussed above as an answer to your post, let me know and I'll add one.

Comment: Yes, for the community it is important, excellent idea, specially the part of nested method calls about how timeout is ignored vs how timeout is **not** ignored if the method is called directly from the Main class. (My First experiment).. Do emphasis too about is necessary have an interaction with the DB to let work the timeout too.

Comment: Summary should be a new post, the second, not included in the first and not how a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your first logs (related to timeout issue with `recordInvoice` vs. `checkStockAvailability`), these do indicate that transactional behavior is applied properly: at Java code level transactions are started and committed. The only difference in logs is that with `recordInvoice` there is an actual query being executed against the database while with `checkStockAvailability` there is no such thing.

A possible answer to this would be that if there is no activity with the database, then there is no database level transaction. What you have in java code reflect at db level. If, for example, you open a MySQL console and insert something in a table, at the end you need to commit to see the results in DB.

Related to your second issue, where you are using `JdbcTemplate` for one test and Hibernate (with `HibernateTransactionManager`) for the other, looking at the [source code for the Hibernate transaction](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.1.0.Final/org/hibernate/engine/transaction/internal/jdbc/JdbcTransaction.java#83) it seems that only values strictly greater than 0 are considered. So, a simple test that involves setting the timeout to one second while in the transactional method `checkStockAvailability` one could add a `Thread.sleep(1500)` could reveal that 0 second values for timeout are simply ignored explaining the results of your tests.

Comment: Thanks again by your valuable support Andrei.